# Checking if a user exists on the database and return user in JSON format

Tags: algorithm, php, api, database

below code takes data (*email,password,user type*) from `$_POST[]` and use them to search whether a user exists on the database. If yes sends a JSON object to the client and also stores cookies on the browser.

I have two user types and have them stored in two tables in my database.

- User_Table
- Driver_Table

I need to change the database tables depending on the user type because I have used common `SQL` statement for both.
For that, I have implemented `selection($userType)` in `credentials.php`

---

**SQL Statement**

*`$sql = "SELECT * FROM $credentials->userTable WHERE email='$credentials->email'";`*

---

`./lib/database.php` contains the database connection details and connects to the database.

**in** **Log_In.php**

```
include "./lib/user.php";
include "./lib/credentials.php";
include "./lib/database.php";

$userDetails = json_decode($_POST["m"]);
$credentials = new credentials($userDetails);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $credentials->userTable WHERE email='$credentials->email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//checking the user details
if($result->num_rows === 1) {
    $details = $result->fetch_assoc();      
    $validate = password_verify($credentials->password,$details["userPassword"]);

        if($validate === TRUE){
            if($login_record === TRUE){
                $user = new user($details);
                $user->userType = $credentials->userType;
                $user->loggedInStatus = true;
                $credentials->setCookies($user);
                echo json_encode($user);
                $conn->close();
                }
        }
        else {
            echo "error";
            $conn->close();
            }

}
```

**In credentials.php**

```
class credentials {

    public function __construct ($credentials) {

        $this->email = $credentials->email;
        $this->password = $credentials->password;
        $this->userType = $credentials->userType;
        $this->userTable = $this->selection ($credentials->userType);
    }



    public function selection ($userType) {
        if ($userType === 'driver') {
            return "Driver_Details";

        }
        if ($userType === 'passenger') {
            return "User_Details";
        }

    }

    public function setCookies ($user) {

        foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
           setcookie($key,$value,time()+86400,"/");
        }
        setcookie("t",time(),time()+86400,"/");


    }
}
```

**in user.php**

```
class user {
    public function __construct ($details) {
         $this->userName = $details["name"];
         $this->userLocation = $details["country"];
         $this->userId = $details["User_ID"];
         $this->loggedInStatus = false;
         if (isset($details["driverVehicle"])) {
             $this->userVehicle = $details["driverVehicle"];
         }

    }
}
```

**I need to check the type of user and change the tables to use more than one time in different php files.**

I'm looking for some expert ideas and suggestions on a better way to change the database table depending on the user type. Mostly because I need to use that on more different php files.

Comment: So you need help changing the functionality of this script?  ...that's not what we do here -- we review code that works exactly as required.  Of course, I should also say that injecting submission variables into your query is not a secure/stable practice.

Comment: mickmackusa This code is working as required. I'm looking for some ideas about changing the ´´´´user table´´´´ depending on user type. Using it on many php files a good practice? How should i set submission variables to my sql?